# Tools helpful for setting up virtual test environment

Tags: linux, networking, deployment, kvm-virtualization, chef

I'm looking for something similar to vagrant, but working with KVM. I'd like to setup a couple of machines with packages I point at using a single command, but I don't really want to write the whole script from scratch. The things which are required:

- setting up a single network between those machines and a nat for the world
- setting up groups of servers separately (for example I want a separate group of database-like servers and a group of app servers so that i can redeploy one of them)
- some interaction with chef, so that I can push the right config at the beginning and spawn some machines only after another machine finished its first chef-client run
- extensibility so that I can easily add missing functionality (I'd like a package rebuild / apt repository update as a part of the deployment)

Answer (score 1):

First rule of thumb with VMs (KVM or other) is that you can always treat them as normal physical machines. So chef, cobbler, puppet etc are all valid solutions for their purpose.
Deploying VMs is easier than physical machines, because you have the option of creating a template of a certain generic setup, and simply clone or snapshot the existing image, turning it into a new VM.

Comment: I'm ok the low-level tools and could put a solution together myself, but I'm looking for some framework which will put those things together in one place (their generalised config, that is)

Comment: I guess you'd want to look at ovirt.org when it finally opens up (should be by the end of the year), or at the higher end systems, like RHEV

Comment: OpenStack is probably the closest you'll get, but it doesn't sound like you need any more configuration management than what Chef already gets you. You should only need to set up NAT once.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe OpenStack isn't configuration management, it is APIs made of services that provide a utility computing platform for managing virtual machine images and instances.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it was; I was replying to viraptor's comment and question.